# playing encrypted files using SDL_Mixer

Tags: c++, encryption, sdl-mixer

I have some encrypted mp3 files that I would like to play from my program using SDL_Mixer. All the documentation I've come across have only shown how to load music by specifying a path and file name, and I haven't come across an example that plays files that were previously encrypted. I have an algorithm for decrypting the file, and was wondering if it was as basic as adding a callback to an SDL_Mixer function that would decrypt the file on-the-fly. If this can't be done with SDL_Mixer, what audio library can do this?

Comment: Must be some seriously top secret music you got there. Will the MP3 files also self-destruct by exploding upon being played all the way to the end?

Comment: Yes, they will, killing any poor sap who happened to be listening to them.

Answer (score 0):

The music functions generally don't support loading from memory, because their purpose is to stream music from disk (to conserve resources). If you want to load something from memory, you need to use the sample functions instead.

[Mix_LoadWAV_RW](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Mix_LoadWAV_RW) takes in an [SDL_RWops](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_RWops), which is a "half-documented" object that resembles a file. The documentation page has functions for creating such an object from a piece memory, but if you want to decrypt on the fly, you'll have to create your own.

Comment: I have another question: will Mix_LoadWAV_RW accept mp3's? I'm pretty sure I'm doing the decryption correctly in memory, but when I do Mix_LoadWAV_RW, I get this error: Unrecognized sound file type